# Python Date arrays

Tags: python

I have the following 3 arrays.

```
years=[2011,2012,2012]
monthes=[01,02,03]
days=[10,20,30]
```

Is there a way to turn them to into array of dates *without using a loop* , meaning a method/library that can combine integers arrays into date array?

```
dates = [2011/01/10,2012/02/20,2013/03/30]
```

Comment: -1 for ridiculous restriction

Comment: @isedev: In Python 3.x, it's a `SyntaxError`, but in 2.x, it's perfectly valid; he's just specifying the numbers `1`, `2`, and `3` in octal for no good reason. Then again, that _last_ line is pretty obviously not valid…

Comment: @abanert valid point (I was using 3.x).

Comment: By not using loop, I thought that there is a method that can combine integers array into date array, I've edited my question, thanks for you comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(lambda t: "/".join(map(str, t)), zip(years, monthes, days))
```

Comment: `map` has a loop inside of it.

Comment: @abarnert: True, the CPython implementation does. Depending on the implementation used, `map` could be implemented without a loop.

Comment: Well, it's defined as working "for every element of iterable". I suppose if you wrote an implementation that acted indistinguishably as if it were looping over an iterable but were actually, say, using recursion with TCO, that might be valid, but that seems like a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes. At any rate, I get the impression that the OP just wanted to avoid using an explicit loop.

Comment: @abarnert , OP is new to Python, ofcourse I didn't mean that a loop won't be executed at the end of the day (as mipadi mentioned), I was wondering if there are shortcut in Python of doing it without writing the loop myself (which I know how to do). I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any loops, you have to "unroll" things manually. This is almost always a very silly thing to do, and this case is no exception, but whenever you know the length of things statically, it can be done:

```
dates = []
dates.append('{}/{:02}/{:02}'.format(years[0], monthes[0], days[0]))
dates.append('{}/{:02}/{:02}'.format(years[1], monthes[0], days[1]))
dates.append('{}/{:02}/{:02}'.format(years[2], monthes[2], days[2]))
```

I've left a copy-paste-and-edit error in there for you to debug, as a demonstration of exactly why "Don't Repeat Yourself" is a fundamental principle in programming, and therefore why "without a loop" is a silly requirement.

---

Alternatively, you can always turn any loop into a recursive call, but (a) this is a very silly thing to do in Python, and (b) most computer scientists would probably say that's still a loop. But if you really wanted to:

```
def format_dates(years, monthes, days):
    if not years:
        return []
    return (['{}/{:02}/{:02}'.format(years[0], monthes[0], days[0])] +
            format_dates(years[1:], monthes[1:], days[1:]))
dates = format_dates(years, monthes, days)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dates = ['/'.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(years,months,days)]
```

Example:

```
>>> years=[2011,2012,2012]
>>> months=['01','02','03']
>>> days=[10,20,30]
>>> ['/'.join(map(str,x)) for x in zip(years,months,days)]
['2011/01/10', '2012/02/20', '2012/03/30']
```

Comment: You have two loops here, one explicit one in the list comprehension, and another one hidden inside `map`.

Comment: @abanert not to mention a loop in `zip` ;)

Comment: Well, this being Python 3, you could argue that loop gets folded into the `map` loop, because `join` only does a single iteration over its argument which just happens to be an iterator built on another iterator… but yeah, you're right, I missed it. :)